# Validation of angular form without submit button

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using anuglar.js form validation.
I want to check validation without form submit button.

This is my html.

```
<form name="userForm">
  <input type="hidden" ng-model="StandardID" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="50" required>
    <span ng-show="userForm.Name.$dirty && !userForm.Name.$valid">Name is required.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Alias:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Alias" placeholder="Alias" maxlength="50" required>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="update()">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

My  controller js is.

```
$scope.update= function () {
    alert($scope.userForm.Name.$valid);
    if ($scope.userForm.Name.$valid) {
        alert("Entry added");
    }
}
```

It shows small dialog that says this field is required. I don't want this popup . Why span section does not show?

Comment: not working. i did it before but i don't know what is wrong in this code. why span section is not showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it, the key is use the `name` attribute in your `<form>` and in all of your inputs. 
Following this way, angularjs will create a form instance where you can access all fields like `myForm.myInput.$invalid`

For example:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>     
    <label>My Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.myInput.$dirty && myForm.myInput.$invalid">My Input is invalid.</span>
</form>
```

Check angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: yes working but with this "Please fill out this field" notification dialog also visible. how to remove it?

Comment: Where do you see that notification? Is the browser notification when you submit the form? Try to put <form name="userForm" novalidate>

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<form name="cutome_form" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>

   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="Name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="50" required>
                              <div ng-show="cutome_form.name.$dirty && cutome_form.name.$invalid">
                                 <span class="error" ng-show="cutome_form.name.$error.required">The field is required.</span>
                              </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">Alias:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="alias" class="form-control" ng-model="Alias" placeholder="Alias" maxlength="50" required>
                        </div>
    <div ng-show="cutome_form.alias.$dirty && cutome_form.alias.$invalid">
      <span class="error" ng-show="cutome_form.alias.$error.required">The field is required.</span>
    </div>

  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="cutome_form.$invalid">Submit All</button>
</form>
</div>
```

directive

```
  .directive('ngModel', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            elem.on('blur', function() {
                ngModel.$dirty = true;
                scope.$apply();
            });

            ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
                ngModel.$dirty = false;
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                elem.off('blur');
            });
        }
    }
});
```