# $touched not working in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following line's of code. When I use `$touched` I still don't get the warning when I remove focus from the textarea. Can someone point out what I could be doing wrong here? 

I am using angularjs v1.5

```
<textarea ng-model="ctrl.PendingRequest.BusinessJustification"
          name="BusinessJustification"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Minimum of 10 characters"
          ng-minLength="10"></textarea>

<div class="warning"
     ng-if="!ctrl.check('BusinessJustification') && BusinessJustification.$touched">
     Business justification is required
</div>
```

Comment: You should use a `<form></form>`. Are you using it? If not, try to wrap everything inside a form. Check this answer to clarify what I'm trying to explain https://stackoverflow.com/a/42311013/3354228

Comment: Perfect thank you :)